# Get average difference between all numbers in a list (python)

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list where I'd like to get a sense of the difference between all the numbers in it. Algorithmically, it seems like I should take the absolute value of the subtraction of each item from a list from each other and then to find the average of the sum of subtractions. *Don't worry about absolute value part. That's only relevant to my application.*

For example:

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4]

list_a0 = (abs(1-2) + abs(1-3) + abs(1-4))/3 = 1+2+3 = 2
list_a1 = (abs(2-1) + abs(2-3) + abs(2-4))/3 = 1+1+2 = 1.33
list_a2 = (abs(3-1) + abs(3-2) + abs(3-4))/3 = 2+1+1 = 1.33
list_a3 = (abs(4-1) + abs(4-2) + abs(4-3))/3 = 3+2+1 = 2
avg = (lista0 + lista1 + lista2 + lista3)/4 = 1.67
```

I'm newer to python. Would someone be able to give a tip on how to loop through `list_a` to do this?

Comment: I don't see any subtraction going on...

Comment: I don't follow... your example doesn't seem related to your question. Where are these subtractions occurring? What are those sums you are illustrating?

Comment: A list comprehension is for creating *lists*. Are you creating a `list`? If not, then you don't want a list-comprehension. If you are, you *may* want a list comprehension, if it is nice and readable.

Comment: @CoryKramer sorry I clarified.

Comment: `abs(1-3)` is not `3`

Comment: @schwobaseggl sorry I clarified.

Comment: `[sum(abs(l[i]-l[j]) for j in range(len(l)) if j!=i) for i in range(len(l))]`

Comment: @schwobaseggl then use `statistics.mean` on it.

Comment: This should be easily solved with 2 loops, which would likely also be more readable than a list comprehension. Have you made an effort to code a solution? If so, what problems did you run into?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, the mean should not be the main issue :)

Comment: Don't let people bring you down. I had the same question and because of you I found the answer!

Answer (score 6):

Consider using numpy package which is super efficient and rubust.
here is example:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list_a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a = np.array(list_a)
>>> np.diff(a)
[1,1,1]
```

takes 9.489059448242188e-05 seconds which is 0.00009 second

Answer (score 3):

From your example, it appears that you are trying to loop over all permutations of the list of length 2. Luckily, itertools has a function just for that:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list_a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> diffs = [abs(e[1] - e[0]) for e in itertools.permutations(list_a, 2)]
>>> sum(diffs)/len(diffs)
1.6666666666666667
```

If you don't want to use itertools, I advise using a for loop rather than trying to squish this into a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> list_a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> diffs = []
>>> for i, e in enumerate(list_a):
        for j, f in enumerate(list_a):
            if i != j: diffs.append(abs(e-f))

>>> sum(diffs)/len(diffs)
1.6666666666666667
```